Is timber less likely to bow when weight is on its thinnest side?
I've built a little "ceiling" shelf out of some spare C16 CLS timber (L)2.4m (W)63mm (T)38mm that I had.
Currently the weight of the contents of the shelf sit onto of the 63mm side and the timber is bowing slightly.
My question is, if I rotate the timber so the weight sits on the 38mm side, is it less likely to bow under the same weight?

Have you ever seen a beam that wasn't upright? There's your general answer. For something more useful, maybe ask about your specific project instead. I'm not sure what a "ceiling" shelf is (or why it's quoted).

Pictures would help.

Educate yourself here, if you like: https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/ The "secret weapon" in this sort of situation is using a stressed-skin panel for your shelf, possibly. But the sagulator will allow you to investigate how solid lumber will behave in different orientations and different loadings,

@isherwood - haha fair point yeah....the irony is that the shelf is attached to timber that way :/

Resistance to wood bowing/sagging is determined by its depth.
63mm will hold more than 38mm, but is thinner, so you want to double it to have the same space/area to hold stuff.
Another way is to add more support to reduce the open span.  Another support in the centre will increase the holding power/reduce bowing.
There are tables online that will tell you the depth of wood needed over an open span to stop/reduce bowing/sagging.

For space reasons, I cannot at further support beams without raising the entire platform. I'm trying to find a shortcut to reduce the work. The timber frame currently holds the plywood shelf on the 63mm side, based on what you've said I can flip the 4 pieces of timber round so the plywood sits on the 38mm and it'll be less likely to bow - which is the result I'm after.

@Cheetah   It will be less likely, but does depend on the weight on top.  All wood sizes has a weight limit to prevent bowing/sagging/breaking.  The open span you have does limit the weight.  I would be quite nervous walking across it at half my weight.
